# How to abort a lengthy nodejs function based on mongo query?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb

The basic architecture is:

1. My client sends an `AJAX` request to my `node`
2. My `node` makes an entry of the request in `mongo`, sets the status 'process' and starts a lengthy function
3. When the function returns it updates the status of the request in `mongo` to 'completed'
4. My `node` sends back a response to the client after verifying with `mongo`

Now suppose the client sends an another request to my `node` while the previous request is being processed saying that the previous request is to be aborted. My `node` promptly updates the previous request's status in the `mongo` to 'abort'.

Now how do I make my `node` to quit that function?

One thing I can do is to put a few checks in my function to check if the status has been updated to 'abort', if yes then return then and there.

My `mongo` checks would have to be synchronous and the only way i can think of doing it is by putting `callback`s inside `callback`s and so on. My function already has a few `callback`s and adding a few more will make it even more unmanageable.

Can anyone suggest me a better way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694573/nodejs-performance-optimization) - currently I am creating separate DB connections for each client and simply closing them in response to an early disconnect but there could be better ways of doing it, we'll see (: